# Prevent switching language on AWS client while using hotkeys that includes switching language hotkey of local system

Tags: amazon-workspaces, language-switching

The problem is that whenever I use Alt+Shift as part of some hotkey (for example for switching opened windows in revert order Alt+Shift+Tab) on AWS, local system switches the input language (AWS is not blocking handling key press on local system) and AWS changes input language to the the language of local system (I left only one input language, but it ignores that).

How can I handle key pressing only in scope of AWS or how can I forbid using input language of local system on AWS client.

I already left only one input language on AWS - it doesn't helped at all.
Also checked different options in settings of AWS client OS and didn't find any helpful option.